# Move UIBarButtonItems up inside a UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I've created a custom instance of UIToolbar to use a background image, and with my particular image, the actual toolbar is a smaller height than than the image itself (eg. the toolbar is 60px and the lower 20px is transparent, with a small item on the side). This somewhat confuses UIToolbar because all UIBarButtonItems are forced to be centred vertically, which doesn't align with my image.

Is there a margin or something I can set to get the button to slide upwards? I've considered UIButtons but I would need an image to match the look of the existing toolbar, so I'd prefer to have the buttons generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, but this might work: `- (void)setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:(CGFloat)adjustment forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics` for `UIBarButtonItem` class.

Reference: [UIBarButtonItem class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment%3aforBarMetrics%3a)

Answer (score 0):

With recent iOS versions, the only way I could make this reliably work is by adjusting the content view of the `UIToolbar`. In my `UIToolbar` subclass I have the following code in `layoutSubviews`:

```
if ( _preferredHeight )
{
    [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull v, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        NSString* className = NSStringFromClass(v.class);
        if ( [className localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:@"content"] )
        {
            v.frame = CGRectOffset( self.bounds, 0, 2 * (44 - self->_preferredHeight) );
            *stop = YES;
        }

    }];
}
```

**Note that this peeks around in the `UIToolbar` private subview hierarchy and may not be AppStore-safe or break in future iOS versions.**